# Get id (category or business) from url after mod rewrite and assign into variable in php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The actual URL's are like - 
`/category.php?id=2` and `/product.php?id=56` . I applied the following rules in my htaccess file -

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^.+/p/([0-9]+)   product.php?id=$1    [NC,L]
RewriteRule   ^.+/c/([0-9]+)   category.php?id=$1    [NC,L]
```

And i am getting the following url patterns -

```
/c/2 and `/p/56`
```

Upto this it is fine
Previously i could get the ID's of category and product from like `?id= 2` by GET method. But get method will not work after rewrite. How can i get the ID's also the page type (category,products)?

Comment: For product `http://example.com/product-permalink/p/id` for category `http://example.com/category-permalink/p/id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^.+/p/([0-9]+)   product.php?id=$1    [QSA,L]
RewriteRule   ^.+/c/([0-9]+)   category.php?id=$1    [QSA,L]
```

QSA means that if there's a query string passed with the original URL, it will be appended to the rewrite.

L means if the rule matches, don't process any more RewriteRules below this one.

Comment: So with this i can catch strings by GET method?

Comment: But what should i write on the link ref of the category in previous page? Should it be written as `category.php?id=2` or `/c/53` ? If the second one then actually it is not passing any id right?

Comment: @TanjimaTani use `/c/53`

Comment: Ok. then what should be the index of `$_GET['']` as the href didn't send any index?